# How to reduce space between panels using plot margin to combine plots of different dimensions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, layoutmargins

I want `fig1` to span over three columns, and I have three versions of `fig4` that need to be in row 2, in each column.

```
set.seed(111)
f1 <- data.frame(forest.type = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), times = 36 ),
           sp.type = rep(c("X","Y","Z"), times = 48),
           time.type = rep(c(1:12), each = 12),
           number.type = rnorm(144))
fig1 <- ggplot(aes(x = time.type, y = number.type), data = f1) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + facet_grid(forest.type ~ sp.type, scales="free")   +  
  theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(aspect.ratio = 10/20) + 
  ggtitle("These wont stretch across the three columns")


fig4 <- ggplot(aes(x = time.type, y = number.type), data = f1) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +   theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5) + 
  ggtitle("All this goes in \nrow 2")

fig1 <- fig1 + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))
fig4 <- fig4 + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,-10,1),"cm"))
```

[image]

I tried various versions of the `plot.margin` but I am not able to get fig 1 to span all three columns. Also, I only get this figure when I use `zoom` in. When I try to save it to the plot dimensions I need (21 cm height and 16.5 width), the figure get smushed. In the "Zoom" in version the axis text size is too tiny and doesn't match up with the other figures I'm printing for the manuscript.

EDIT: I tried `cowplot` as suggested. However, I face similar problems..

```
set.seed(111)
f1 <- data.frame(forest.type = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), times = 36 ),
                 sp.type = rep(c("X","Y","Z"), times = 48),
                 time.type = rep(c(1:12), each = 12),
                 number.type = rnorm(144))
fig1 <- ggplot(aes(x = time.type, y = number.type), data = f1) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + facet_grid(forest.type ~ sp.type, scales="free")   +  
  theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(aspect.ratio = 10/20) + 
  ggtitle("These wont stretch across the three columns")

fig1 <- fig1 + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))
fig4 <- fig4 + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))

library("cowplot")
ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(fig1, x = 0, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 0.5) +
  draw_plot(fig4, x = 0, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = .5) +
  draw_plot(fig4, x = 0.3, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = .5) +
  draw_plot(fig4, x = 0.6, y = 0, width = 0.3, height = 0.5) +

  draw_plot_label(label = c("A", "B", "C","D"), size = 15,
                  x = c(0, 0, 0.3, 0.6), y = c(0.5, 0, 0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: I would use patchwork or cowplot.

Comment: @zephryl Patchwork is absolutely terrible. It messes up the tex sizes. I tried `cowplot` put it still poses similar issues (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach, if you don't mind giving the first row more height the first plot can  stretch across the 16.5cm page by adjusting row height in the call to `patchwork::wrap_plots`. Alternatively you could adjust row height and `theme(aspect_ratio...)` to achieve the desired output.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)


set.seed(111)
f1 <- data.frame(forest.type = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), times = 36 ),
                 sp.type = rep(c("X","Y","Z"), times = 48),
                 time.type = rep(c(1:12), each = 12),
                 number.type = rnorm(144))
fig1 <- ggplot(aes(x = time.type, y = number.type), data = f1) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  facet_grid(forest.type ~ sp.type, scales="free")   +  
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 10/20) + 
  ggtitle("These wont stretch across the three columns")


fig4 <- ggplot(aes(x = time.type, y = number.type), data = f1) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +   theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5) + 
  ggtitle("All this goes in \nrow 2")

fig1 <- fig1 + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))
fig4 <- fig4 + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,-10,1),"cm"))

design <- "AAA
           BCD"

wrap_plots(fig1, fig4, fig4, fig4,
           design = design,
           heights = c(3, 2))+
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')

ggsave("comb_plots.png", width = 16.5, height = 21, units = "cm")
```

Results in:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>